# Custom Template From Variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap's typehead, which provides an attribute: **typeahead-template-url**, which can be used to set a custom HTML template to display the typehead items. In the example, this is set as: customTemplate.html in HTML and the template is created as so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
      <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>
```

Can I define this template in my main JavaScript file, as opposed to creating a script tag for it, as above?

I am looking for something like:

HTML:

```
<input typehead=".." typeahead-template-url="tpl.html" />
```

JS:

```
Angular.setTemplate( 'tpl.html', '<a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a>' )
```

Comment: $templateCache.put("tpl.html", "<a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a>") ?

Comment: Yes, this works. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.